# python code with list and loop not providing expected output

Tags: python

I have the following code which does not list out the bedrooms or baths with the number :

```
room = ('Bath','BedRoom')

for k in range(0-6):
    room = room[1] = str(1+k)
    print room
```

I wanted to see the output as 'Bedroom1','Bedroom2'...............'Bedroom6'

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here and appreciate your inputs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
room = ('Bath','BedRoom')
for k in range(1,7):
    print room[1] + str(k)
```

Note that `range(0-6)` evaluates to `range(-6)` because it is doing `0 - 6` as subtraction.

Output

```
BedRoom1
BedRoom2
BedRoom3
BedRoom4
BedRoom5
BedRoom6
```